# What does "-" mean in R within []

Tags: r

For example:

```
stars(utilities[,-9], labels = as.character(utilities[,9]))
```

The `utilities` is a data.frame, and it has 9 columns and the 9th is the name.

What does `-9` mean?

Comment: Please read `help("[")`.

Comment: if you are unsure what a command does...just try it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
stars(utilities[,-9], labels = as.character(utilities[,9]))
```

will run `stars` on `utilities` without the 9th column, and use that column as the labels.

Negative indices in subscripts cause selection of everything *except* those items/rows/columns.